# Dynamic webpage titles

Tags: wp-title

We have statistical website made on elementor which is showing covid-19 cases updated continuously all day similar to https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus .
This website's page title changes as their page statistics changes. For instance this page https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/
title is - United States Coronavirus: 1,013,128 Cases and 57,037 ... and figures changes in title as page updates. How to this done?

Thanks

Comment: You’ll have to provide some code that we can work with.  This can actually be done with jQuery to manipulate the page title, but we’d need to see where the updated number comes from.